# Need help formatting CONCAT() for MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a table where I am attempting to take 3 database table values and reformat them in a single value.  Here is the SQL statement that I have at the moment:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN cb_cardtype = 'Discover Credit Card' 
       THEN 'DS' 
       END + 
       ';' + RIGHT(cardnumbers,4) + ';' + LPAD(MONTH(planexpdate), 2, '0') +
       '/' + LPAD(YEAR(planexpdate), 2, '0') AS account_billing_key 
FROM my_table
```

So what I wanted to get as an output here would be:

`DS;4242;07/14`

The problem is that I am using the `+` to attempt this, which actually adds the values together.  Rather, I understand that I need to use `CONCAT()` to merge the values.  I am unclear about how I can pull the individual values and then concatenate them as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query is otherwise correct, all you need to do is to wrap all the strings you want to concatenate - comma separated - inside a call to [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat);

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN cb_cardtype = 'Discover Credit Card' THEN 'DS' END, 
    ';', 
    RIGHT(cardnumbers,4), 
    ';', 
    LPAD(MONTH(planexpdate), 2, '0'),
    '/', 
    LPAD(YEAR(planexpdate), 2, '0')
  ) AS account_billing_key 
FROM my_table
```